# ionic-cordova app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have recently started working on ionic platform and I have very little info on cordova. My cordova plugin is similar to this :
https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-hello
Similar to cordova-plugin-hello/src/android/Hello.java file, I have a file MyPlugin.java and the execute method looks like this:

```
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray data, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if (!isInit) {
        init();
        isInit = true;
    }

    if (action.equals("runCommand")) {
        String command = (String) data.get(0);
        String authToken = (String) data.get(1);
        LOG.d(TAG, "command - " + command);

        String result = ReSdk.getInstance().runCommand(command, authToken);
        callbackContext.success(result);

        return true;
    } else if (action.equals("registerEventCallback")) {
        eventCallbackContext = callbackContext;

        PluginResult pluginResult = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK);
        pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true);

        eventCallbackContext.sendPluginResult(pluginResult);

        return true;
    } else {

        return false;

    }
}

 @Override
 public void onEvent(String command) {
   if (eventCallbackContext == null) {
   LOG.e(TAG, "eventCallbackContext is NULL");
   return;
   }

PluginResult pluginResult = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, command);
pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true);

eventCallbackContext.sendPluginResult(pluginResult);
 }

  @Override
  public void onHighTrafficEvent(String command) {
  if (eventCallbackContext == null) {
  LOG.e(TAG, "eventCallbackContext is NULL");
  return;
  }

PluginResult pluginResult = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, command);
pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true);

eventCallbackContext.sendPluginResult(pluginResult);

}
}
```

and similar to www/hello.js, I have a file :

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');

module.exports = {
runCommand: function (command, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "MyPlugin","runCommand", [ command]);
},

registerEventCallback: function (success, err) {
    // TODO - handle event management here and emit them
    cordova.exec(success, err, "MyPlugin", "registerEventCallback", []);
}
};
```

I want to call the methods onEvent and onHTEvent from ionic app.

Now, my requirement is such that I have an event in cordova plugin which I want to call from my ionic app(earlier we were using websockets for connection, we want to remove them and have simple event calls).
I have been going through a lot of links available on internet but none of them I could relate to. 
If anyone could share any useful information regarding this, would be great!

Comment: Which cordova plugin? Maybe explain specifically what you're trying to do.

Comment: updated, I hope now it makes more sense.